# Click a button on a website using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click a button on a website using selenium.
Here's the html:

```
<form action="/login/" id="login" method="post" class="form-full-width">
   <input data-testid="loginFormSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-large" value="Log in" 
   tabindex="3">
</form>
```

Here's some of my code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
    driver.get ('https://www.url.com/login/')
    driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys('username')
    driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('password')
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@value='Log in' and @type='submit']")
```

I have also tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_value('log in').click()
```

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='https://www.url.com/home/']").click()
```

However when I run it, it always comes up with this error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href='https://www.url.com/home/']"}
```

I am new to selenium and web drivers, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try a capital L in Log in. The element is "Log in" and you are looking for "log in", so Selenium can't find it. Python is case-sensitive.

Comment: Nope, sorry, that was just an error in my question. Still doesn't work though- still comes up with the error message

Comment: the xpaths are incorrect. find_elements returns a list of element. You have to use find_element method if you are targeting only one element. You can try the following xpath -  //input[@data-testid="loginFormSubmit"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[data-testid='loginFormSubmit'][value='Log in']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@data-testid='loginFormSubmit' and @value='Log in']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)